# How to combine the advantages of `int` and `NSInteger`

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnumber

A seemingly simple question: Can I have some sort of Number object, which can be nil but which I can assign like a primitive int:

like this:

```
NSNumber *n = nil; 
n = 3; 

if(n == nil){ 
    // some actions... 
} else if (n == 1){ 
    // some actions... 
} else { 
    // some actions... 
}
```

Thanks for your input

Comment: NSInteger is not the same as NSNumber. NSNumber is a class, while NSInteger is a typedef.

Comment: why arent you using NSInteger or int?

Comment: It's true that using a primitive int might be the simplest solution, but I like the fact that an object can be "empty" thus nil, which is obviously not possible with an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is NO. If the variable is an object you can either assign another object,

```
n = anotherNSNumber;
```

or, set the value by using *properties* or by *methods*,

```
n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
```

and, compare the object with another object,

```
if (n == anotherNSNumber) // Checks the reference
```

or compare its value by using *properties/methods*,

```
if (([n intValue] == 3) || ([n intValue] == [anotherNSNumber intValue]))
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer as others have mentioned is "No".
But the following slight modification to you code will achieve a similar result:

```
NSNumber *nObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3]; 
int n = nObject.intValue; // Zero if nObject is nil

if(nObject == nil){ 
    // some actions... 
} else if (n == 1){ 
    // some actions... 
} else { 
    // some actions... 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that n is 0 if nObject is nil? I'd rather guess it remains uninitialized, and could have any value.

Comment: The value of n really is zero when nObject is nil. That's because a message send to a nil object will always returns nil and nil is the address zero.  `NSNumber *nObject = nil; int n = nObject.intValue; NSLog(@"Value of n is %d", n);` will output "Value of n is 0"

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The reason for that is that `nil` is a pointer to the address `0x0` i.e. `nil == 0`. So you won't be able to disambiguate between `0` and `nil`.

Not to mention the fact they are also supposed to be different types. `nil` is used as a pointer whereas a number like 0 or 3 is a scalar.

`nil` is defined as

```
#define nil NULL
```

A typical definition of `NULL` goes like this:

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you think you can. No.

when you say:

```
NSNumber *n = nil;
```

what you are saying is *declare a pointer that points to an NSNumber object, but for now have it point to nil* This is okay; because what you might do later is to get a pointer to an NSNumber object and then assign it to this variable so that `n` is then a pointer no a valid NSNumber object.

With your next line:

```
n = 3;
```

You are not assigning a value to the object, but you are saying that `n` points to the address 3. Which isn't an address and which doesn't contain an object.